# Webform Module can't send email from user anonymous

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

I'm using Drupal 7 and Webform Module for create contacts forms (This problem also what I have in Pressflow 6).

Only authenticated users can send mail through the form. However, I need that anonymous users can also use the form.

The error is as follows:

```
Error sending e-mail from sender@email.com to target@mail.edu.pe: SMTP Error: Data not accepted.
SMTP server error: 5.7.1 Sender domain not allowed.
```

How I can make the form send mail with both roles (authenticated and anonymous)?
How I can avoid spam for users anonymous?

### Details

Each time you use the contact form (either anonymous or authenticated) to send an email to the person responsible of receiving these emails.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous users can absolutely submit webforms. On the Form Settings page under submission access, there are permission checkboxes for each role. You can use [Captcha](http://drupal.org/project/captcha) or [Mollom](http://drupal.org/project/mollom) to help prevent spam submissions.

[image: Role permissions for webform.]

The error you're having seems like you have SMTP misconfigured. Are you currently using the SMTP module? If so, run a test to send an email to yourself. If that fails, then it's definitely the problem.

Comment: Yes. I have SMTP module. I run a test to send an email and the result is OK. My SMTP module is correctly configured.
The error only appers with anonymous user.

Comment: In form settings I have the 2 roles checked.

Comment: Try turning off the SMTP module, clearing cache, and then submitting a form as an anonymous user. I'm not saying this will fix it, but I really don't think it's an issue with Webform.